# Doubt on Always-on ApplicationIntend-ReadOnly and ApplicationIntend=ReadWrite

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, load-balancing

I Have Deployed Always-on, and I have routed read query into secondary server, but my question is that, how can I make connection string on application side which will divert. Insert, Update and Delete to Primary server and Select query to Secondary server. Do I need to create two connection string? or one connection will be okay.......... I am in confusion any insight will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/connect-to-sql-server-using-application-intent-read-only/ba-p/317758) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to configure multiple connection strings for this purpose, so 1 for the ReadOnly, and one for the changes. Brent has a good article about this:

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/10/my-favorite-connection-string-tips/